# Background-images on my new project, switching between mac and pc home/at school

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website for a school project, and I am using different background images on each site. I am also fairly new to html/css/Js. In school, I use my Macbook Pro, and at home, I use my windows desktop. My problem is this, when working at school, I download the images to my OneDrive folder, and insert them in my Visual Studio Code index.html with something like this:
`/Users/edward/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-KristeligGymnasium/Kristelig Gymnasium VG2/Informasjonsteknologi 1/HTML/Datakomponenter - nettsideoppgave/Resources/Pictures/serverrom.jpeg`

But on my windows desktop at home, the file path is different even though it is the same picture:

`E:\Onedrive - Kristelig Gymnasium\Kristelig Gymnasium VG2\Informasjonsteknologi 1\HTML\Datakomponenter - nettsideoppgave\Resources\Pictures\motherboardbackground.jpeg`

I don't even know if that is the problem itself, but for the explanation, when I run the website at home, the pictures don't work because windows don't understand the path, hence there is no background image. I want to be able to send my folder to my teacher so that he can see my full, and working website.

Thanks for the help :)

I don't really understand what to do differently, as I am new.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Datamaskiner og informasjonsteknologi | Nettsideoppgave</title>
    <link href="Resources/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Resources/css/sidemenu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Resources/js/functions.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body id="home">
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

body#home {
    background: url("Resources\Pictures\motherboardbackground.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: You should use an actual static server.  I don't mean that you need to buy a whole dedicated server, I mean, you should use a static server program to serve your content while you develop locally instead of using something like `file://`.  There are a lot of choices depending on your preference.  Look into something like apache2 or just **any** static server that you can run locally.  Usually your IDE will even have a way to host content to avoid this problem.

Comment: You need a static server like MAMP

Comment: You need to go to your online folder and create 'embedded code' for that particular image. Read this [MS: Embed files directly into your website or blog](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-files-directly-into-your-website-or-blog-ed07dd52-8bdb-431d-96a5-cbe8a80b7418)

Comment: But my problem is that I want people on mac and windows be able to open my website with all its content regardless of if I made it on my mac or my windows desktop. The different paths in the code makes it so that (if i understand correctly) windows doesnt understand the mac path and therefore isnt able to get all the content and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact to use a local server as comments saying, there are 2 things in your questions.

First you are giving files full path from mac and windows. But seems your 2 full path don't refer same image.

At the end of first one:
serverrom.jpeg

At the end of second one:
motherboardbackground.jpeg

I don't think Windows change serverrom for motherboardbackground!

if you want to stay with your cloud, you can detect on which platform you are and add the right pre-url to the file name:

you have:

/Users/edward/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-KristeligGymnasium/Kristelig Gymnasium VG2/Informasjonsteknologi 1/HTML/Datakomponenter - nettsideoppgave/Resources/Pictures/serverrom.jpeg

and:

E:\Onedrive - Kristelig Gymnasium\Kristelig Gymnasium VG2\Informasjonsteknologi 1\HTML\Datakomponenter - nettsideoppgave\Resources\Pictures\motherboardbackground.jpeg

Beside the name in your example which I think is a mistake, the last part is same but you'll have to invert / to \ for windows:

/Kristelig Gymnasium VG2/Informasjonsteknologi 1/HTML/Datakomponenter - nettsideoppgave/Resources/Pictures/serverrom.jpeg

First part is platform dependent:

Mac: /Users/edward/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-KristeligGymnasium

Windows: E:\Onedrive - Kristelig Gymnasium

is same

Comment: ah yes, thats my mistake (it is correct in the original code). But if i understand correctly I will have to use a static live server? Where do I find this kind of thing in Visual Studio Code? But yes, my problem was that when I try to test what I created on my Mac, on my windows desktop, nothing works.. Thank you all very much :)

Comment: on mac local server is already installer. On windows you have to install. By the way, it's quite easy and there are plenty of tutorial on that.

Comment: I have the live server thing, but I still dont understand how i can have the entire project folder connected together... By that I mean that people who havent downloaded my pictures will be able to see the backgroundimage when they open the folder on their computer/mac. Also, with the difference in platform dependant paths, how do I add both the windows and the osx path to my project?